# Type not deduced to be r-value reference: why not?

Tags: c++, c++11

Please consider the following code:

```
class CMyClass {};

template<class T>
void func(T&& param) {
        if (std::is_same<CMyClass, std::decay<T>::type>::value)
            std::cout << "param is a CMyClass\n";
        if (std::is_same<T, CMyClass&>::value)
            std::cout << "param is a CMyClass reference\n";
        else if (std::is_same<T, CMyClass&&>::value)
            std::cout << "param is a CMyClass r-value reference\n";
        else if (std::is_same<T, const CMyClass&>::value)
            std::cout << "param is a const CMyClass reference\n";
        else if (std::is_same<T, const CMyClass&&>::value)
            std::cout << "param is a const CMyClass r-value reference\n";
        else if (std::is_same<T, const CMyClass>::value)
            std::cout << "param is a constant CMyClass\n";
        else if (std::is_same<T, CMyClass>::value)
            std::cout << "param is a CMyClass\n";
        else
            std::cout << "param is not a CMyClass\n";
}


CMyClass mc3;
func(std::move(mc3));
```

The output from this little program is

```
param is a CMyClass
param is a CMyClass
```

Why has the type of mc3 not been deduced to be an r-value reference please?

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373881/why-forwarding-reference-does-not-deduce-to-rvalue-reference-in-case-of-rvalue

Comment: _"Why has the type of mc3 not been deduced to be an r-value reference please?"_ Because it isn't one?

Comment: Your code checks what the type of `T` is, but then prints a lie about the type of `param`. The type of `param` is `T&&` not `T`, so your program lies. Now, what type do you need to substitute for `T` to make `T&&` equal to `CMyClass&&`? So what is `T`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find a good dupe for this even though one must exist somewhere, sorry.

The deduction rules for:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T&& )
```

in the context of a call `foo(expr)` are:

- If `expr` is an lvalue of type `U`, then `T` is deduced as `U&` and the type `T&&`  is `U&`, due to reference collapsing.
- If `expr` is an rvalue of type `U`, then `T` is deduced as `U` the type `T&&` is `U&&`, due to reference collapsing.

In your example, `std::move(mc3)` is an rvalue (specifically an xvalue) of type `CMyClass`. Hence, `T` is deduced as `CMyClass`. This check:

```
else if (std::is_same<T, CMyClass&&>::value)
    std::cout << "param is a CMyClass r-value reference\n";
```

will almost never be true as `T` will never deduce as an rvalue reference type. It could be specifically provided as such:

```
func<CMyClass&&>(std::move(mc3));
```

but that's an unlikely usage. What you can do instead is check:

```
else if (std::is_same<T&&, CMyClass&&>::value)
//                    ~~~~
```

That will handle all cases where the argument is an rvalue. Indeed, if you simply always check for `T&&`, that will handle all of your cases properly.

Comment: In your second bullet you also end with "due to reference collapsing"... but there isn't any collapsing (there's just a single `&&` application involved)?

Answer (score 3):

> Why has the type of mc3 not been deduced to be an r-value reference please?

If `param` is an *rvalue*, `T` is a *non-reference* inside `func`, and `T&&` is an *rvalue reference*. Here's an example that empirically shows what `T` means in the body of a function that takes a *forwarding reference*:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T&& x)
{
    std::is_same<T, something>{}; // (0)
    std::is_same<T&&, something>{}; // (1)
}
```

In the case of **(0)**:

- `T` *is*  `T` when an *rvalue* is passed to `func`. **(*)**
- `T` *is* `T&` for when an *lvalue* is passed to `func`.

In the case of **(1)**:

- `T&&` *is* `T&&` when an *rvalue* is passed to `func`.
- `T&&` *is* `T&` when an *lvalue* is passed to `func`.

If you use `std::is_same<T&&, CMyClass>::value`, you should either get a `T&` or `T&&`.

---

**(*)**: note that the term "is" is inaccurate - the various meanings of `T` inside `func` depend on  [*template argument deduction*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) and [*reference collapsing*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing).

In short:

- `T` is deduced as:

  - `T&` if `x` is an *lvalue*.
  - `T` otherwise.
- Due to *reference collapsing*, `T&&` is:

  - `T&` if `x` is an *lvalue*. *(`T& &&` -> `T&`)*
  - `T&&` otherwise. *(`T&& &&` -> `T&&`)*

Comment: @EdgarRokyan that's true for *prvalues*, but I think it is deduced as `T&&` for *xvalues*. Nevertheless, I will amend my answer to mention that *reference collapsing* is happening.

Comment: What does `T` is deduced as anything mean in the context of `something<T>()`? There's no deduction going on in that line.

Comment: @Barry: changed `something` to `std::is_same`. What I am trying to say is that the "meaning" of `T` and `T&&` inside the body of `func` change depending on how `T` was deduced and depending on the effects of reference collapsing. Evidently having trouble with terminology

Comment: @Barry: is my answer still misleading *(if so, how can I improve it)*?

Comment: It's better. But now you're using `T` to mean two different things on the same line (e.g. `T` is `T&`)