# Why deduced types of fun(T t) and fun(T && t) are different in C++?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

```
template <typename T>
void fun1(T t) {} 

template <typename T>
void fun2(T && t) {}

int i = 1;
fun1(i); // the deduced type of T is int
fun2(i); // the deduced type of T is int &
```

The deduced type of T in fun1(i) and fun2(i) are `int` and `int &` respectively, can anyone explain the mechanism how compiler do deduction?

#### UPDATE

This question is not a duplicate of [Type not deduced to be r-value reference: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145453/type-not-deduced-to-be-r-value-reference-why-not), because:

The later question explained the deduction rules for :

```
template <class T>
void foo(T&& )
```

**Here, I want to know the difference of deduction rules for**

```
template <class T>
void foo(T&& )
```

and

```
template <class T>
void foo(T )
```

Comment: What would you expect instead? Both `int` and `int&&` would make `t` an rvalue reference, which could not be bound to `i` which is an lvalue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type not deduced to be r-value reference: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145453/type-not-deduced-to-be-r-value-reference-why-not)

Comment: No, it's not. See UPDATE please. @E_net4

Comment: The difference is that they are different function signatures.  `fun1(T)` is always passed by value, and `fun2(T&&)` is deduced according to the rules explained in the linked duplicate.  They aren't related otherwise.

Comment: I know fun2(i) is passed by lvalue reference, but why fun1(i) is passed by value rather than lvalue reference? @thirtythreeforty

Answer (score 0):

That is aperfect forward which can produce different outcomes depending on what arguments are provided to the template.

> Perfect forwarding reduces the need for overloaded functions and helps
>   avoid the forwarding problem. The forwarding problem can occur when
>   you write a generic function that takes references as its parameters
>   and it passes (or forwards) these parameters to another function. For
>   example, if the generic function takes a parameter of type const T&,
>   then the called function cannot modify the value of that parameter. If
>   the generic function takes a parameter of type T&, then the function
>   cannot be called by using an rvalue (such as a temporary object or
>   integer literal).
>
> Ordinarily, to solve this problem, you must provide overloaded
>   versions of the generic function that take both T& and const T& for
>   each of its parameters. As a result, the number of overloaded
>   functions increases exponentially with the number of parameters.
>   Rvalue references enable you to write one version of a function that
>   accepts arbitrary arguments and forwards them to another function as
>   if the other function had been called directly.

[Rvalue Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668.aspx)

> Forwarding references
>   Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve the value category of a function argument, making it possible to forward it by means of std::forward. Forwarding references are either:

1. function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same function template:
2. auto&& except when deduced from a brace-enclosed initializer list.

[Forwarding Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

How it is donde is explained here:
[Template Deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call)

Answer (score 0):

Because the type of `i` is `int`, not `int&`. As [[temp.deduct.call] paragraph 1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1) says

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template 
>   parameter type (call it P) that contains template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it A) as described below.

And [[temp.deduct.call] paragraph 4](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#4) says

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A (after the type A is transformed as described above).

The forwarding reference case is a special case. As [[temp.deduct.call] paragraph 3](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3) explicitly says

> If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.