# Forwarding reference does not deduce to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, template-argument-deduction, forwarding-reference

First, this question has been asked by others, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373881/why-forwarding-reference-does-not-deduce-to-rvalue-reference-in-case-of-rvalue) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145453/type-not-deduced-to-be-r-value-reference-why-not), but (I think) neither of them provides a satisfactory answer.

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction),

> Before deduction begins, the following adjustments to P and A are made:
>
> 1. If P is not a reference type,
>    a) if A is an array type, A is replaced by the pointer type obtained from array-to-pointer conversion;
>    b) otherwise, if A is a function type, A is replaced by the pointer type obtained from function-to-pointer conversion;
>    c) otherwise, if A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored for deduction:
> 2. If P is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored for deduction.
> 3. If P is a reference type, the referenced type is used for deduction.
> 4. If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called forwarding reference), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, the type lvalue reference to A is used in place of A for deduction
>
> After these transformations, the deduction processes as described below (cf. section Deduction from a type) and attempts to find such template arguments that would make the deduced A (that is, P after adjustments listed above and the substitution of the deduced template parameters) identical to the transformed A, that is A after the adjustments listed above.

Using this rule, we look at the following code, with `type_name` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766138/12217673):

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo(T && t) {
    std::cout << type_name<T>();
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    foo(std::move(a)); // int, not int&&
}
```

From rule 3, since **P** = `T &&` is a reference type, the referenced type `T` is used for deduction, i.e. deduced **A** is `T`.

**A** is the type of `std::move(a)`, which is a rvalue of type `int &&`. No transformation is applicable, so transformed **A** is `int &&`.

To make deduced **A** identical to transformed **A**, we shall have `T = int &&`.

But the code above shows `T = int`. Is this an inaccuracy of cppreference, or my misunderstanding?

Comment: I think you are wrong in saying that the type of `std::move(a)` is `int&&`. It is not; an expression never has a reference type. It's type is `int`, but its category is xvalue.

Comment: Reread the answers on the duplicate, `T` isn't an rvale reference but `t` is, i.e. your function deduces to `void foo(<int> && t)` not `void foo(<T &&> t)`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment there to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions [can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1), so the type of `std::move(a)` is `int`, not `int &&`.